# how to show chinese word , not unicode word

Tags: python, string, list, utf-8

this is my code:

```
from whoosh.analysis import RegexAnalyzer
    rex = RegexAnalyzer(re.compile(ur"([\u4e00-\u9fa5])|(\w+(\.?\w+)*)"))
    a=[(token.text) for token in rex(u"hi 中 000 中文测试中文 there 3.141 big-time under_score")]

    self.render_template('index.html',{'a':a})
```

and it show this on the web page:

```
[u'hi', u'\u4e2d', u'000', u'\u4e2d', u'\u6587', u'\u6d4b', u'\u8bd5', u'\u4e2d', u'\u6587', u'there', u'3.141', u'big', u'time', u'under_score']
```

but i want to show chinese word , so i change this:

```
a=[(token.text).encode('utf-8') for token in rex(u"hi 中 000 中文测试中文 there 3.141 big-time under_score")]
```

and it show :

```
['hi', '\xe4\xb8\xad', '000', '\xe4\xb8\xad', '\xe6\x96\x87', '\xe6\xb5\x8b', '\xe8\xaf\x95', '\xe4\xb8\xad', '\xe6\x96\x87', 'there', '3.141', 'big', 'time', 'under_score']
```

so how to show chinese word in my code,

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, printing a larger built-in structure gives the `repr()` of each of the elements. If you want the `str()`/`unicode()` instead then you need to iterate over the sequence yourself.

```
a = u"['" + u"', '".join(token.text for token in ...) + u"']"
print a
```